# How to make a 2x3 piston door?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The idea is just a regular, somewhat compact 2x3 redstone door with the sticky pistons and all, but it seems improbable to have it so that when it opens up, the three levels open at a separate interval, that being the bottom opening first, then the middle then the top, the main problem being that any piston seems to power the piston below.

Any suggestions or is this actually not possible?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade. Would you mind posting a screenshot that outlines more in detail what you're after? The description in words alone is rather difficult to understand. The community would be much more likely to post a helpful answer if the question was more clear.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is so unclear that people vote on closing it? It could be a little easier to undersand with pictures, or maybe a simpler explaination, but that doesn't make the question unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You're facing an issue due to [quasi-connectivity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity). Working around quasi-connectivity can get fairly difficult sometimes, but it's very useful for many things, too.

A 0-tick pulse does not trigger quasi-connectivity, so a structure like this will only move the diamond block:

[image: Setup for a 0-tick pulse and three pistons, where only one piston gets activated by that pulse]

Repeaters update before comparators do, so after you push the button the repeater will send a signal through the gold block. Then the comparator powers the sticky piston, which pushes away the gold block, so the redstone signal ends in the same tick as it started.

This triggers the middle piston and neither of the other two pistons, it then imidiately retracts. A sticky piston will not pull a block if it received a very short redstone pulse and it pushed a block due to that pulse.

If you use that knowledge, then you could build something like this:

[image: setup for one side of a 2x3 piston door]

This can be used for a 2x3 piston door, where the lowest block opens and closes first and the highest block last. The offset can easily be controled with the repeaters on the right side and you can add more repeaters for even more offset.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the famous bug [MC-108](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-108), a more specific [report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-3610) says that powering a higher piston without also powering the lower piston is impossible. So yes, your door sadly is indeed impossible. MC-108 is incorrectly marked as "works as intended", but you can at least vote for MC-3610 if you want it fixed.